# Visual Studio 2019 C# "Find All References" hides "Symbols without References" under "Not Applicable"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, overriding, find-all-references

When I used Visual Studio 2017 in the past, and opened the references panel for a method (SHIFT + F12), all references and implementations to the method would be listed separately, even if a particular override of the method does not contain references to the base method (It'd simply say "No references found to 'class.method'" under the listed override method"):
["Screenshot - Find All References in VS 2017"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpXU2.png)

After switching to Visual Studio 2019, I believe the "Find All References" window behaved the same, until today (I could have simply not noticed the change until now):
["Screenshot - Find All References in VS 2019"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQXLf.png)

Now, only references of the method are dislayed normally. There is a separate "Not Applicable" category at the bototm of results, with a "Symbols without References" category that's collapsed by default. I can only find derived methods there (unless the child class actually calls the method; Even an override that uses the "base" keyword wouldn't be shown outside of "Not Applicable").

I find it very inconvenient that implementations of a method are hidden under "Not Applicable" by default, and need to be manually expanded. Plus, "Symbols without References" are listed in a way that's hard to navigate at a glance.

I have tried changing "Group By" - Any options without "definition" would show all the method overrides in detail that are otherwise hidden. I would like to group the results by definition though (as I always had grouped by "Project then Definition" in the past - I've never encountered the current behaviour before). My current compromise is to group by "Project then Containing Type".

Did I accidentally change some settings on "Find All References", or is this simply a change in VS2019? Is there any way I could revert the references display back to how it was before?

Answer (score 0):

`Not applicable` is also the default behavior in VS2022. I didn't find any settings related to Find All Reference.

You can submit a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/dotnet) to the developer community.

Comment: Thanks. This wasn't the case in VS2017, so I guess the references window got changed past that.

Comment: You could post the feature  request link here so that we can follow up.